# How to zoom part of the screen?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, zooming

I am trying to zoom a part of a screen. For example, I've got a ListView and I want to make static field on the middle which is making this part of ListView larger. I've extended ListView and overrided onDraw, where I am getting drawing cache and computing my box.
onDraw is being called with every scroll, by this.invalidate(), but no matter when I scroll, the zoomed box doesnt change (zooms the same position of the listview). How can I change it? Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    buildDrawingCache();


    bitmap = getDrawingCache();
    shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(shader);
    matrix.reset();
    int width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, width / 2, height / 2);
    paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    canvas.drawRect(40, height / 2, width, height / 2 + 300, paint);

}
```